# What is nLog's version of log4net's %property

Tags: nlog

With log4net I could do

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["custom1"] = "value";
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["custom2"] = "other value";
```

And inside the config file I could just put

```
"|%logger|%message|%newline%property"
```

And it would render the entire ThreadContext Dictionary.

I have found something called MDC in nLog but can't find anyway to dump the MDC dictionary bag.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

While defining the target in the configuration, you have to provided the layout. For example:

```
<target xsi:type="Console" name="c" layout="${mdc:item=custom1}" />
```

But this will only render the custom1 value. There are no way to render all the properties in the MDC.